# On Mac OS terminal, How do I prevent mycli from forwarding query results to a text viewer

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, vi

On Mac OS terminal, How do I prevent **mycli** (mysql client) from forwarding query results to a text viewer.

Comment: you want to present it in another editor or no editor at all ?

Comment: no editor at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable mycli's pager option by either adding the following to ~/.myclirc and ~/.my.cnf configuration files

```
enable_pager = False
```

or directly from mycli console by typing

```sh
$ nopager
```